# Proof that $\lim_n\frac{\ln(1+x_n)}{x_n}=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given a sequence of real numbers $x_n$ that converges to $0$ and $\vert x_n \vert <1$, $x_n \neq0$, I must prove the following limit:

$\lim_n\frac{\ln(1+x_n)}{x_n}=1$

What I have tried is:

$\lim_n\frac{\ln(1+x_n)}{x_n}=\lim_n\frac{1+x_n}{e^{x_n}}=\frac{1}{1}=1 $

However, I don't feel like this is right. How can I improve this?

Comment: That is definitely not right. Note that $$
\frac{{\log (1 + x)}}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x {\frac{{dt}}{{1 + t}}}  = \int_0^1 {\frac{{ds}}{{1 + xs}}} 
$$ and so $$
\frac{{\log (1 + x)}}{x} - 1 = \int_0^1 {\frac{{ds}}{{1 + xs}}}  - \int_0^1 {ds}  = -x\int_0^1 {\frac{{s ds}}{{1 + xs}}} .
$$ Can you conclude?

Comment: Use taylor's theorem

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x_n)}{x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+x_n)-\ln(0)}{x_n}
=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)-\ln(0)}{h}
$$
is the derivative of $\ln$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use L'Hôpital's rule, as the functions are differentiable and the derivative of the denominator is not zero:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\text{log}(1+x_n)}{x_n} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\text{log}(1+x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{1+x}}{1} = 1 .$$
The first equality follows simply as the functions are continuous, so in the limit they do not care about the specific sequence.